# ffmpeg can play video but not a stream containing the same data

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg-4

This is my first time encountering video codecs/video streaming.

I am receiving raw h.264 packets over TCP. When I connect to the socket, listen to it and simply save the received data to a file, I am able to play it back using

```
ffplay data.h264
```

However, when I try to directly play it from the stream without saving it, using

```
ffplay tcp://addr:port
```

all I get is the error

```
Invalid data found when processing input
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I found another way to display the video stream.

```
ffplay -f h264 -codec:v h264 tcp://addr:port?listen
```

The `?listen` parameter makes it so ffplay creates its own tcp server. All I do now is send the data to the specified address.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the format: `ffplay -f h264 tcp://addr:port`

Comment: I tried it with `ffplay -vcodec h264 tcp://addr:port` but maybe that was the wrong parameter. I'll check later. Thanks for now!

Comment: That sets the decoder but not the demuxer. Mine sets the latter and the decoder is autoselected.

Comment: I tried `ffplay -f h264 -codec:v h264 -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 tcp://addr:port` still without any luck

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Do you mean the IP address? Sure, it's simply `127.0.0.1:8889`